# BootstrapDialog.confirm not Waiting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an issue con button click, I show a BoostrapDialog.confirm but there is a postback before clicking (yes or no)

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{     
    <a href="#" data-pdsa-action="3" data-pdsa-turno="@item.Id" data-pdsa-val="@item.Id" onclick="return BootstrapDialog.confirm('¿Desea tomar el turno @item.Fecha.ToShortDateString() @item.Hora ?');" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
                                    </a>
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try adding a little more code, I do not see any code for Bootstrap here.   Also your razor markup has an extra @ symbol prefixing the Html.BeginForm()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I fixed the error, removed @ and updated to the last version of BoostrapDialog.